# Sensor/servo shield for Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, shields

Is there Arduino shields with blocks of 4 pins that you can plug your servos into and use the fourth pin as signal pin to the Arduino Mega board?

Comment: You could (probably) easily make this yourself (using an Arduino prototype board and some pin-headers) or buy an arduino "servo controller shield".
Also, Arduino.Stack Exchange isn't the place for shopping recommendations, you could ask suppliers/manufacturers if they have such a thing available.
It's also a little unclear, do you want the 3 servo's to receive the same signal? You could simply attach them to the same header and "short", solder or jumper the pins together.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like a [sensor shield](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/SensorShield#SSM)? They have three pins (Vcc, GND, signal), not four (because servos have three pins), but they are designed for connecting a large number of servos [image: Arduino Mega sensor shield]

These can be found easily and cheaply all over the internet.